# Div "modal-content" control does not appear until mouse pointer is hover on it while running on remote machine

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute a `Selenium` script written in `C#` on a remote machine, for Continuous Integration, on `IE 11`. My application has a `div modal-content panel` which has some fields and a Save button. On clicking the save button another `div modal-content popup` should appear. But it remains hidden unless I hover the mouse pointer on top of it (not just anywhere on the screen, but exactly over it).

Hence my script is failing.

> Note: The script executes absolutely fine on my local machine. Also on
>   the remote machine it does not show this issue all the time ! It
>   happens randomly.

Please help.

As designed in our automation framework, we have the below components:

File A – This class file contains the tests steps – call to functions. The below section of the code clicks on the edit link, updates a few things, clicks on the Save button on which another pop-up appears and clicks on the Save button present on the modal.

```
private FormDesigner FormDesigner { set; get; }

// Clicks on the edit link
FormDesigner = FormPanel.ClickEditLink();

// Update a few things
FormDesigner.RemoveFormFields(2);

// Clicks on the Save button 
FormDesigner.ClickSave();

// Clicks on the Save button present on the div-modal
FormDesigner.ClickSaveOnSaveForm();
```

File B – This class file acts as a library containing all the functions called from File A. For example,

```
public FormDesigner ClickEditLink()
{
    EditLink.Click();
    return new FormDesigner(_webDriver);
}

public void RemoveFormFields(int fieldToRemove)
{
    FormDesignerFields(FormFieldRemove).ElementAt(fieldToRemove).Click();
}

public void ClickSaveButton()
{
    FormSaveButton.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

public void ClickSaveOnSaveForm()
{
    SaveFormSaveButton.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

File C – This class file contains all the element locators (XPaths) of the webelement. Functions present in File B use these locators to perform any action. For example,

```
private const string FormFieldRemove = <XPath>;
private const string FormLnk = <XPath>;
private const string FormDesignerBtn = <XPath>;
private const string SaveFormSaveBtn = <XPath>;

protected Link EditLink
{   
    get { return new Link(_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(FormLnk)), "Edit", true); }
}

private ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FormDesignerFields(string formFields)
{
    return _webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath(formFields));
}

protected Button FormSaveButton
{
    get { return new Button(_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(FormDesignerBtn))); }
}

protected Button SaveFormSaveButton
{
    get { return new Button(_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(SaveFormSaveBtn))); }
}
```

File D – This class file contains all the operations that can be performed on a particular web component. For example, here we are showing Button and Link. For example,

Button class file:

```
private const string _buttonXPath = ".//button[contains(.,'{0}')]";
private const string _buttonValueXPath = ".//input[@value='{0}']";
private IWebElement _button;

public Button(IWebElement webElement, string name, bool byValue)
{
    _button = byValue ?   webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(_buttonValueXPath, name))) : webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(_buttonXPath, name)));
}

public void Click()
{
    _button.Click();
}
```

Link class file:

```
private const string _linkXPath = ".//a[text()='{0}']";
private const string _linkContXPath = ".//a[contains(.,'{0}')]";
private IWebElement _link;

public Link(IWebElement webElement, string value, bool useXpath)
{
    _link = useXpath ? webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(_linkXPath, value))) : webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(_linkContXPath, value)));
}

public void Click()
{
    _link.Click();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth posting the code that shows the modal.

Comment: I have added a sample of my code.